# Is drawing in a canvas the best way to make a game?

Tags: android, canvas, google-play-games

i'm developing a game for fun and I have the intention to publish the code on GitHub once I'm finished. But since I am going to publish it, I want to do the best code I can, and I am starting by drawing the scenario into a canvas. So here's my questions, is drawing in a canvas the best way? or is there another way?
and another one: I need to draw more or less 50 rectangles(they will be the floor), and right now I am loading the .png into a View and drawing it into the canvas like thisÇ

```
Barra barra1 = new Barra(new Point(3*getWidth()/25 - (context.getDrawable(R.drawable.barra).getIntrinsicWidth()),2*getHeight()/12 - (context.getDrawable(R.drawable.barra).getIntrinsicHeight()/2)),context,context.getDrawable(R.drawable.barra).getIntrinsicHeight() + (getHeight() /100),context.getDrawable(R.drawable.barra).getIntrinsicWidth() + (getWidth())/100);
    barras.add(barra1);
    Barra barra2 = new Barra(new Point(10*getWidth()/41 - (context.getDrawable(R.drawable.barra).getIntrinsicWidth()),2*getHeight()/12 - (context.getDrawable(R.drawable.barra).getIntrinsicHeight()/2)),context,context.getDrawable(R.drawable.barra).getIntrinsicHeight() + (getHeight() /100),context.getDrawable(R.drawable.barra).getIntrinsicWidth() + (getWidth())/100);
    barras.add(barra2);
```

and so on, is that also the best way? Accepting sugestions.

Comment: I don't have any experience with creating games, but I know there are frameworks for that, I assume that using a framework would be the best way, and they come with tutorial to show you how it's done:

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I'm aware of the frameworks, but i really want to do this in code so I can publish it and help the comunity :)